# What could hang system to a point where mouse and keyboard are unresponsive

Tags: windows, windbg

I have a full dump of a VM with windows 10 installed. This dump was taken from a hard hanged system, frozen mouse and keyboard, totally unresponsive.

While analyzing I found that there are no thread in running or ready state. No deadlocks. Only suspicious thing is that there are a lot of thread waiting for a reply from ALPC and also there is page fault pattern in as lot of threads that looks like this:

```
        ffffbc0f`151380f0 fffff805`1e4e081c Ntfs!NtfsNonCachedIo+0x4ea
        ffffbc0f`151383b0 fffff805`1e4df8bc Ntfs!NtfsCommonRead+0xd2c
        ffffbc0f`151385b0 fffff805`19687d3a Ntfs!NtfsFsdRead+0x1fc
        ffffbc0f`15138680 fffff805`19687ce7 nt!IopfCallDriver+0x46
        ffffbc0f`151386c0 fffff805`1d926ccf nt!IofCallDriver+0x17
        ffffbc0f`151386f0 fffff805`1d9248d3 FLTMGR!FltpLegacyProcessingAfterPreCallbacksCompleted+0x28f
        ffffbc0f`15138760 fffff805`19687d3a FLTMGR!FltpDispatch+0xa3
        ffffbc0f`151387c0 fffff805`19687ce7 nt!IopfCallDriver+0x46
        ffffbc0f`15138800 fffff805`196215b2 nt!IofCallDriver+0x17
        ffffbc0f`15138830 fffff805`196221e2 nt!IoPageReadEx+0x1e6
        ffffbc0f`151388a0 fffff805`19622eee nt!MiIssueHardFaultIo+0xb6
        ffffbc0f`151388f0 fffff805`19666566 nt!MiIssueHardFault+0x48e
        ffffbc0f`151389f0 fffff805`197aba1e nt!MmAccessFault+0x276
        ffffbc0f`15138b00 00007ffd`2e42ec10 nt!KiPageFault+0x35e (TrapFrame @ ffffbc0f`15138b00)
```

also almost every thread (maybe I've seen 1 or 2 that don't) in every process ends with this:

```
        ffffbc0f`15d08df0 fffff805`1966aad4 nt!KiSwapContext+0x76
        ffffbc0f`15d08f30 fffff805`196657ca nt!KiSwapThread+0x190
        ffffbc0f`15d08fa0 fffff805`19666fb0 nt!KiCommitThreadWait+0x13a
        ffffbc0f`15d09050 fffff805`1e4e261a nt!KeWaitForSingleObject+0x140
```

I have one particular example of a thread with a page fault belonging to a prl_tools_service.exe (which is Parallels VM related service) that has same pattern and when looking into trap frame at the moment of KiPageFault there was an attempt to get value from an address in eax and in trap frame rax=0000000000000001 which can't be a valid address and I can't see how this page fault can be resolved.

IRQLs of both processors are LOW_LEVEL

The question, basically, is - where should I look for any faults since there must be a kernel problem (hence mouse and keyboard freeze) and how do I find wether this example of page fault pattern could stall the kernel.

Since the question is pretty vague any kind of response, a direction where to look, a hint - every thing will be much appreciated

UPD: as requested by Lieven Keersmaekers and blabb here is !analyze -hang output:

```
0: kd> !analyze -hang
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Unknown bugcheck code (0)
Unknown bugcheck description
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000
Arg2: 0000000000000000
Arg3: 0000000000000000
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------

Scanning for threads blocked on locks ...
Cannot get _ERESOURCE type

BUGCHECK_CODE:  0

BUGCHECK_P1: 0

BUGCHECK_P2: 0

BUGCHECK_P3: 0

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

PROCESS_NAME:  System

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x45474150 - <Unable to get error code text>

SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!PpmIdleGuestExecute+1d

MODULE_NAME: nt

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x0_STACKPTR_ERROR_nt!PpmIdleGuestExecute

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {94784d45-ed21-c95f-fc42-87fec626bbee}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

Comment: How have you determined that there aren't any deadlocks? If all threads are waiting on kernel objects that's a strong indication for a deadlock.

Comment: !locks output does not show any critical sections, just that.

Comment: Critical sections aren't a prerequisite for a deadlock. A system can deadlock on any waitable object.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep looking into possible wait chains then

Comment: What does `!analyze -v -hang` returns?

Comment: if it is hang dump you can also use [!analyze -hang](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-analyze)  switch

Comment: I updated my post with analyze -hang output. Seems to show nothing of interest.

Comment: i am not sure if you have an usable dump. sorry nothing pops out other than putting it under microscope and peering inside.